# Mouse arrow stops at times

Tags: windows-7, windows, usb, mouse

Few days ago I started having problems with my mouse. Every couple of minutes, my mouse arrow would stop for a second or two, and then suddenly jump to the location it should have been had it not stopped. Other system applications (music, typing) don't experience this lag. 
I tried plugging mouse in to another USB port, updating drivers and firmware, but it didn't help. I don't remember installing any weird software (only windows updates) prior to that.
Any ideas on what I should do?

Comment: It seems as if something is hogging the CPU, probably a system process. It may be faulty hardware generating streams of interrupts. If you run Process Explorer (see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653 - it doesn't need installing) it may show you what has been stopping the handling of your mouse movements.

Comment: I have eight core CPU, and if it was hogging the entire CPU, I think the music would glitch as well?

Comment: So you have an 8 core. That doesn't mean nothing can go wrong. You should still check with Process Explorer just to make sure. Have you ran virus and malware scans to make sure the system is clean? Any warnings or errors in Event Viewer?

Comment: checked process explorer, nothing at odds, system idle at 97% scanned for viruses last week, avast is always active. will check event viewer next time it happens.. thx

Comment: Just happenned again, no errors/warnings in Event viewer.. :/

Comment: Grasping at straws now: have you tried a different mouse? Maybe plug both in, and when it happens with the current one, see if the system responds to the other. On the occasions when I have seen this problem it has been because my system was short of RAM, and the system spent its time thrashing in and out of swap, but that would show up in ProcExp on the system information page.

Comment: No peaks in System Information.. and the frequency of occurence is inconsistent.. I'll try using trackpad to eliminate the mouse problem, I have no other mouse . if anyone has any other ideas, please post.. thanks

Comment: Also, if the problem was mouse, wouldn't the arrow then continue from where it stopped, and not jump to the location it's supposed to be?

Answer (score 0):

First are you using a Wireless mouse? If so that may lag.

Assuming the above question is false, I would try to open the Device Manager and uninstall the mouse driver and reboot and let windows install it again.

Have you tried that mouse that is having problems on another computer? If you try that mouse on a different computer, and the mouse lags again then it is a hardware problem. If not it is either a software or driver issue.

If that fails could you please post the model of the mouse and maybe try searching the manufacture site for updated drivers.